# Cassandra crashed, found suspect objects in MAT analysis

Tags: cassandra

One of the node in a cluster is crashed and when I try to analyze using MAT I see following suspects in the report.

Can any one please help me to understand if there is a problem with Cassandra version,etc?

Version: apache-cassandra-3.11.4
Cassandra Xmx: 13G

java version :1.8.0_45

Last message in Debug log:

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:47,182 MessagingService.java:1236 - MUTATION messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 1 internal and 1 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 16314 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 16410 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:47,182 MessagingService.java:1236 - REQUEST_RESPONSE messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 6 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 15855 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:47,182 StatusLogger.java:47 - Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
WARN  [GossipTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:47,431 FailureDetector.java:278 - Not marking nodes down due to local pause of 13948176954 > 5000000000

DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:51,763 FailureDetector.java:284 - Still not marking nodes down due to local pause
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:51,763 FailureDetector.java:284 - Still not marking nodes down due to local pause
DEBUG [GossipTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:51,763 FailureDetector.java:284 - Still not marking nodes down due to local pause
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-03-04 21:27:51,746 WARN  [Service Thread] 2022-03-04 21:27:53,329 GCInspector.java:282 - G1 Young Generation GC in 1155ms.  G1 Eden Space: 608174080 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 12492994960 -> 13214415248; G1 Survivor Space: 88080384 -> 29360128;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2022-03-04 21:27:53,329 StatusLogger.java:47 - Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
```

Highly appreciate on any tips further to explore?

Suspect 1:

```
One instance of “org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher$LegacyFlusher” loaded 
by “sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x48062f2e0” occupies 1,856,054,480 (18.04%) 
bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of “java.lang.Object[]”, loaded by 
“<system class loader>”, which occupies 1,856,054,136 (18.04%) bytes.
```

Suspect 2:

```
One instance of “org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher$LegacyFlusher” loaded 
by “sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x48062f2e0” occupies 1,521,968,760 (14.79%) 
bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of “java.lang.Object[]”, loaded by “<system class loader>”, which occupies 1,373,989,312 (13.36%) bytes.

Keywords

org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher$LegacyFlusher

sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x48062f2e0
java.lang.Object[]
```

Comment: When it "crashed", what was the last full error message + full stack trace? Also what version of Java are you using? It would be great if you could edit your original question and include this info.

Comment: @ErickRamirez- Please suggest your views. Added details.

Comment: fyi.. Interestingly I don't find any StackTrace in logs but heap dump

Answer (score 0):

The constant pauses reported by `FailureDetector` indicate to me that your node is most likely in a GC spiral and the heap dump is just a consequence of the node being overloaded.

Consequently if this is really the last entry in the `debug.log`:

```
INFO  [Service Thread] 2022-03-04 21:27:53,329 StatusLogger.java:47 - \
  Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
```

then there's a possibility that the `oom-killer` terminated the Cassandra process, again because of memory pressure.

If this happens repeatedly on the same node, it would point to a hot partition (or set of partitions) and possibly even large partitions that get read repeatedly, filling up the heap.

I've noted that you're running Cassandra 3.11.4 which is quite old. I'm not suggesting you upgrade because of that since there's no evidence the old version is the cause of the issue. But I will say that you should be motivated to upgrade because C* 3.11.4 was released over 3 years ago and there have been over a hundred fixes since then. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your comments Erick. I will try to find if that is something with Large Partitions or not.